# Excel Online Add-in - Adding rows with a function as the value for the first column creates a total row

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js

Having a weird issue with the Excel Online JS Api. I'm creating a new sheet and adding a table with data from an API call. There is a specific case where the first column of the table has a hyperlink function (`'=HYPERLINK("somelink", "Go to Wherever")'`) and after it is being added to the table.rows, one of the rows is being created as the total row.

It always picks the same row to be the total row for the same set of data, but will pick a different row between sets of data. So, it's not always the same index being used.

Here is a snippet of how I'm adding the rows. It's pretty straight forward:

```
.then(function(){

    var dataTable = ctx.workbook.tables.add(topLeftCell.address + ':' + topRightCell.address.split('!')[1], true);

    var headers = data[0];
    var headerRange = dataTable.getHeaderRowRange();
    headerRange.values = [headers];

    for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (!data[i] || data[i].length !== data[i - 1].length) {
             break;
        }
        dataTable.rows.add(-1, [data[i]]);
    }

    dataTable.getRange().format.autofitColumns();
    return util.ctxSync(ctx); 
})
.then(function(){
     worksheet.activate();
     return util.ctxSync(ctx);
 })
```

The worksheet and the table create just fine, but having any formula as the first value in the row will cause one row to be created as the table's total row instead of a normal row. It can get gotten with `dataTable.getTotalRowRange()`, but is not in `dataTable.rows`. It's strange.

I've assumed this is an Excel bug and I can fix it by adding a dummy column with any value that isn't a formula as the first column and then deleting it before the `autofitColumns()`.

Would anyone have any ideas towards a better fix? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Is this only happening in Excel Online or is it happening regardless of platform?

Comment: It's definitely in Excel Online. I haven't had a chance to check other platforms.

Comment: I've confirmed that the behaviour is the same in Excel for Mac.